# How to make images appear side by side on one row on desktop, but responsive and centered above each other on mobile?

Tags: html, css

We have two pages where we're trying to have images appear in one row side-by-side when viewing on a desktop and tablet, but responsive and centered above one another on mobile.  It's working on one page and not on the other-- I'm assuming because the images are too wide on the pages where it breaks, but that makes me think the entire code is faulty. Tips? Suggestions?

The pages are--

http://www.vaporfresh.com/pages/retailers

http://www.vaporfresh.com/

The css--

```
div.jumbo {
background-color: #fff;
width: 100%; 
margin: 6px auto; padding: 2px;
text-align: center;
}

.jumbo img {
padding: 8px;
display: inline;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) { 
.jumbo img {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px auto;
}
}
```

The HTML--

```
<div class="jumbo">
<a href="http://www.amazon.com/gp/aag/main/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&amp;asin=&amp;camp=1789&amp;creative=390957&amp;isAmazonFulfilled=1&amp;isCBA=&amp;linkCode=ur2&amp;marketplaceID=ATVPDKIKX0DER&amp;orderID=&amp;seller=A1ZSBT0HOD7TH4&amp;sshmPath=&amp;tag=rawathletics-20&amp;linkId=L74XRYUS7ROJTOXL" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0943/1886/files/rsz-amazon-logo.jpeg?11379810593739760604" /></a> 
<a href="http://www.soap.com/buy/Brand=Vapor+Fresh" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0943/1886/files/Soap_Logo_CMYK.jpg?14350831404106169407" /></a> 
<a href="http://www.vinemarket.com/buy/Brand=Vapor+Fresh" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0943/1886/files/VineMarket_Logo_CMYK.jpg?14350831404106169407" /></a> 
<a href="http://www.roguefitness.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=vapor+fresh" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0943/1886/files/roguefitness-vapor-fresh.jpg?14350831404106169407" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/juk6ynd4/

Your code is correct, it does work perfectly fine. However looking at the site you're using

```
width: 100%;
```

however the images are in a grid, so you'll need to look through and what is limiting the sizes. For example you've something like this:

```
#div1 {
width: 50%;
}

#div2 {

width: 100%;
}
```

Then

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">
        This DIV will not get any bigger than 50% due to the scaling of div1!
    </div>
</div>
```